# How to make an add/edit/delete function in a structure (C programming)

Tags: c, arrays

I need to make a program that would allow me to 
1: Add entry 
2: Edit entry 
3: Delete entry 
4: Show entry 
5: Display entry
But i'm having difficulties because i have no background on programming. 
I know how to manipulate the functions into the other functions. But i don't know how to create a single variable (Student ID) that would be like a variable bookmark for each other variable.

```
void choice()
{
    int action,counter;
    printf("\t\t\t1. Add entry\n");
    printf("\t\t\t2. Edit \n");
    printf("\t\t\t3. Delete \n");
    printf("\t\t\t4. Display \n");
    printf("\t\t\t5. Search \n");
    printf("\t\t\t6. Exit \n");
    puts("\t\t\tWhat would you like to do today? (1,2,3,4,5,6)");scanf("%d",&action);
    while (counter<=100)
{
    system("cls");
    switch(action)
    {
        case 1: 
        break; 
        case 2: 
        break;
        case 3: 
        break;
        case 4: 
        break;
        case 5: 
        break;
        case 6: 
        break;
        default: puts("Your input is invalid, put only '1'-'6'");
    }
}
}


void inputchoice()
{
    int ichoice;
    system("cls");
    puts("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t[ADD ENTRY]");
    puts("\t\t\t\t[1] Student info");
    puts("\t\t\t\t[2] Students' grades");
    puts("\t\t\t\t[3] Sections");
    puts("\t\t\t\t[4] Curriculum of sections");
    printf("\t\t\t\tWhat would you like input? ");
    scanf("%i",&ichoice);
    switch(ichoice)
    {
        case 1: puts("\t\t\tYou have selected  \n\t\t\tSTUDENT INFO");delay(10);
        BasicInfo();    break;
        case 2: puts("\t\t\tYou have selected  \n\t\t\tSTUDENTS' GRADES");
        break;
        case 3: puts("\t\t\tYou have selected  \n\t\t\tSTUDENT SECTIONS");
        break;
        case 4: puts("\t\t\tYou have selected  \n\t\t\tSTUDENT CURRICULUM");
        break;
    }
}


void BasicInfo()
{
    char student[10];int SNum[MAXIMIUM],SY[MAXIMIUM];
    system("cls");printf("\t\tYou have selected (Add entry)\n");
    printf("Enter the student number: ");scanf("%d",&SNum);
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tYou have entered: \"%d\"\n",SNum);
    printf("\t\t\t\t\tEnter School year: ");scanf("%d",&SY[SNum]);
    printf("%d",SY[SNum]);
}
```

I've read something about pointers such as -> and about structure but im quite not sure about how to apply them to my code. I would be open to suggestions and if you can apply some examples or some references, i would be happy to read some other programs similar to this.

Comment: Initialize your variables, here you are using `counter` uninitialized and you never increment it in the `while` loop, in consequence you end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @DavidRanieri Do you have some suggestions on how i can make the void BasicInfo() better?